# Custom UID for each user created for Firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Please note that this question is same as the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41155905/firebase-authentication-email-password-how-to-set-users-uid). I am not satisfied with the answer and that's the reason why I am asking it anew.

My problem is that I have a lot of data stored in an external API, each with unique ID. I have imported this data into a separate document (let's say users) into firestore from where I will access it into custom application. Additionally, I have authentication. I want for each user in users document to be created with a specific uid and not the one automatically generated from Firebase.

Is this even possible? If not, then what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UID of a Firebase Authentication user is determined by the provider that initially created that user.

This means that the only way to control the UID is to create a [custom provider](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth). Note that this requires that you run code that creates custom tokens for users in a trusted environment, such as your development machine, a server that you control, or Cloud Functions. In that environment, you can then call the [`createCustomToken` API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens#create_custom_tokens_using_the_firebase_admin_sdk), where you pass in the UID of your choice. For an example of this see this [custom username/password provider](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/username-password-auth/functions/index.js#L85) that uses the username as its UID.

If creating a custom provider is not something you want to do, your only alternative is to maintain a mapping between the ID that you have, and the UID that Firebase generates. So for example, you'd store a document with the Firebase UID, and then in there have a field with your own ID for that user, so that you can look up the information in both directions.